# Tool tip on disable component in ext js 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5, extjs6

I am new to the ext js. My requirement is to show tool tip on the disable component ( ex. xtype like 'button', 'textfield','datepicker' etc ) in ext js 6.0.1.

I am thankful if anyone face the same issue and having solution on the same.

Comment: Extjs allows to show tip on disabled components like button.You can use config *tooltip* or use setTooltip() method for button as given in this link:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.button.Button.html#method-setTooltip

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to show tooltips on disabled buttons in Extjs is to change the style specification for `.x-item-disabled` for `pointer-events:none` to `pointer-events:all`

```
<style>
    .x-item-disabled, .x-item-disabled * {
    pointer-events:all;
}
</style>
```

See fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tha)

Comment: This essentially make disabling the button moot, since you will now be able to click it. How would you display the tooltip without allowing it to be clickable.

Comment: The disabled button does not respond to clicks, but does display the tooltip.  Check the fiddle for an example.  The first button is disabled and does not display the message when clicked.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I was trying to use this for a `checkcolumn` and disable in the `renderer`, which may be why I'm getting different behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this programmaticly:

```
var button={
    xtype : 'button',
    tooltip: 'Tooltip',
    text:'Text',
    style: {
        pointerEvents: 'all'
    }
};
```

Or after the component is initialized:

```
button.setStyle({pointerEvents: 'all'});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Button - add tooltip config.

```
var button={
        xtype : 'button',
        id : 'BtnId',
        tooltip:'',
        text:''
};
```

when you are disabling button.

```
button.disable();
button.setTooltip("Message");
```